# Is it possible to use Ninject Named Bindings using ninject.extensions.xml

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have a very simple problem of DI, and wanted to know if there is a way to solve it using Ninject (or any other DI helper).
I have a Data Access interface that is implemented by several Data Sources providers, like DB, Sharepoint, CRM, etc.

I want to use Ninject to get a specific instance of the interface, based on a parameter that contains a code representing one of this implementations.
So far I know that I can do that by using [named bindings](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#simple-constrained-resolution-named-bindings) , but I couldn't find a way to do the same by xml config file (Ninject.extensions.xml).

[Ninject extensions xml](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.xml) provides a way to solve single mappings:

```
<module name="SomeModule">
  <bind service="Game.IWeapon" to="Game.Sword"/>
  <bind service="Game.IWarrior" toProvider="Game.SamuraiProvider"/>
</module>
```

I'd like to do a config like that, but using multiple mappings for the same interface, using a name, a code or the like.

TIA,
Milton

Answer (score 0):

Just add a *name* property

```
<bind service="Game.IWeapon" to="Game.Sword" name="sword"/>
<bind service="Game.IWeapon" to="Game.Dagger" name="dagger"/>
```

Comment: Oh! That easy? I'll try that! Tks Remo!